# Accessing properties file in Spring from Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template with this expression:

```
 <div class="box small">
                                <img th:src="'${@environment.getProperty('pics.path')} + '/' + ${user.id} + '/' + ${pic}"/>
                            </div>
```

but I have this error:

```
Could not parse as expression: "'${@environment.getProperty('pics.path')} + '/' + ${user.id} + '/' + ${pic}" (template: "joan" - line 528, col 38)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your Thymeleaf expression - the first `'` is not correct.

This should work:

```html
<div class="box small">
  <img th:src="${@environment.getProperty('pics.path')} + '/' + ${user.id} + '/' + ${pic}"/>
</div>
```

When creating complex strings using [literal substitutions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions) is more readable - here is your example using this syntax:

```html
<div class="box small">
  <img th:src="|${@environment.getProperty('pics.path')}/${user.id}/${pic}|"/>
</div>
```